# Building an Excel Formula

Tags: excel-formula

I am brand new to building formulas in excel (other than the easy stuff).  I am trying one that is fairly simple, and I am close but can't quite get it to work!

I need to sum the values in column H, only if the value in column F is equal to the value in a specific cell.  Values in column H are numerical, values in F and the specific cell are words.

So if the number in column H is listed as "Ontario" I need the sum.  Numbers in Column H can be any whole, positive number.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You want [SUMIF()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1):

```
=SUMIF(F:F,"Ontario",H:H)
```

Change "Ontario" to the cell reference.

Comment: @Ro-berg Glad to help, please consider marking as correct, by hitting the green check by the answer.